# File Manager showing share files but gvfs folder does not

Tags: 15.10, sharing, atom

File Manager showing share files but gvfs folder does not showing the files.
below are OS details.
ubuntu 15.10

It is happening for specific shares only. Issue is editors like Atom are not able to open the folders in share.

below command does not show that share in the list.

```
gvfs-mount -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this by running below command.

```
pkill gvfs
```

after that i need to remount shares by file manager.